# SCSS if with v-bind in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs3

Is it possible to write if conditions in SCSS with v-bind in Vue 3?

```
<script setup lang="ts"
  interface Props {
    hoverEnabled: boolean;
  }

  const { hoverEnabled = false } = defineProps<Props>();

</script>
```

```
  <div class="layout-block">
    <slot />
  </div>
```

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .layout-block {
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;

    //@if v-bind(hoverEnabled) == "true" - as i know v-bind returns string so tried this too
    @if v-bind(hoverEnabled) {
      &:hover {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```

I know i can do this with class, but I'm curios if this is possible and how it's done

Comment: Have you figured out a way to do this? I have tried everything I can think of and I'm starting to think it's not possible. It is strange that v-binds function correctly when changing attributes, but for some reason they do not function at all with @if statements. This would simplify my code in some rare cases a lot.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. SCSS gets evaluated/compiled at build time, whereas the values of v-bind variables won't be available until rendering time. Of course, build time and rendering time can coincide – e.g. when doing SSR – but, either way, I don't think the feature you're asking for is supported.